# Email notification using jconsole when memory uses by java application reaches to threshold

Tags: jconsole

i want email notification using jconsole , when java application uses more than given threshold memory. Is it possible through Jconsole or not, if it possible how can i achieve this. Can anybody give some examples or clue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could use the JConsole for such tasks, it is just a GUI for JMX. You should use a special monitoring tool, e.g. Zabbix, Nagios, or any other [among dozens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems).